# How to pass ID to delete data in database

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, server-side

I'm still trying to learn how to use database server.

I would like to ask for help on how to pass id value for deleting, adding, and editing columns in my database / table.

Here is my code :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var table = jQuery('#example').dataTable({

         "bProcessing": true,
         "sAjaxSource": "server/data2.php",
          "bPaginate":true,
          "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
          "iDisplayLength": 15,

         "aoColumns": [
                { mData: 'INVOICE' },
                { mData: 'PRODUCT' },
                { mData: 'SIZE' },
                { mData: 'DATE' },
                { mData: 'DDATE' },
                { mData: 'SUPLIER' },
                { mData: 'COST' },
                { mData: 'STATUS' }
        ],
            "columnDefs": [ 
          {   
            "aTargets":[8],  // this your column of action
            "mData": null, 
            "mRender": function(data, type, full){
             return '<div id="container"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="javascript: void(0);" class="click_'+full[0]+'" title="Click to PRINT">PRINT</a></div>';   // replace this with button 
            }
          }
         ]
});
```

here is my table

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>INVOICE</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>SIZE</th>
            <th>DATE ORDER</th>
            <th>DATE DELIVER</th>
            <th>SUPPLIER</th>
            <th>COST</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>FORM</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

here is my sql to call data from the database

```
$sql = "Select s.invoice_number as INVOICE, s.date_order as DATE, s.suplier as SUPLIER, s.date_deliver as DDATE, CONCAT(d.product_name, d.color) as PRODUCT, s.qty as QTY, s.cost as COST, s.status as STATUS, d.size_id as SIZEFROM purchases sINNER JOIN products d on d.product_id=s.p_name WHERE STATUS = 'received'LIMIT 100000";

$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$data = array();
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    $data[] = $rows;
}
$results = array(
    "sEcho" => 1,
    "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
    "aaData"=> $data
);
echo json_encode($results);
exit;
```

I'm still learning on how to use database.

Thanks for those who can give an advice :)

Comment: Where is your server side code?

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass ID to delete data in database

The SQL query string should looks like this in you PHP code:

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM invoice WHERE id = <ID>';
```

---

The question is answered by this, however as I see you have some other issues too.

For example you need to store these IDs somewhere, so you know what to delete. Since you have a table I assume that you would like to fill it with data from the database. For that the basic SQL query string will look like this - if you are not using any filtering:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM invoice';
```

Then you will put the results to your table something like this:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>INVOICE</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>SIZE</th>
        <th>DATE ORDER</th>
        <th>DATE DELIVER</th>
        <th>SUPPLIER</th>
        <th>COST</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>FORM</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            echo "<tr id='row-{$invoice['id']}'>
                    <td>{$invoice['invoice_number']}</td>
                    <td>{$invoice['product_name']}</td>
                    <td>{$invoice['some_field']}</td>
                    <td>{$invoice['some_other_field']}</td>
                    <td>{$invoice['ect']}</td>
                    // ...
                    <td><button class='delete-btn' id='{$invoice['id']}'>Delete</button></td>
                 </tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Notice the extra column. This is where you can place buttons, like I did it with the "Delete" button. Also notice that the button's id attribute is the id of the invoice from the database. There are more better solutions for this, but for start it'll be good, because it's easy to understand.

The reason I placed that ID there, because like this, if you want to delete the row in the HTML table, you can get the ID of the button with javascript/jQuery.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'button.delete-btn', function(events){
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("invoice.php", {
            id
        });

        $('#row-' + id).remove();
    });
});
```

This jQuery function is triggered when the button is clicked. It gets the id attribute of the object you clicked on(the button) and then it sends a post request to the invoice.php with the id parameter - this is the file where you are executing the DELETE query string and passing this ID to the WHERE condition you got from the request. Finally the jQuery function removes the row from the DOM.